# It is possible to convert HTML code into ActionScript?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, tinymce

I have an ASPX web application for my business back-office staff. In one of the back-office modules, I'm using [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) to edit some text before it is saved to a database. The text looks like this:

```
<p data-mce-style="-webkit-margin-before: 0px; -webkit-margin-after: 0px; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 14px; background-color: #f7f7f7;">
    <strong>Is</strong>
     one of the 
    <span style="text-decoration: underline;" data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;">most</span>
     brilliant 
    <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 204, 153);" data-mce-style="background-color: #ffcc99;">ballets</span>
     in the 
    <strong>world</strong>
    . "
    <em>Sleeping Beauty</em>
    " take 
    <span style="color: rgb(51, 153, 102);" data-mce-style="color: #339966;">us</span>
     to an 
    <a href="http://pt.wikipedia.org/" target="_blank" data-mce-href="http://pt.wikipedia.org/">unchanted</a>
    &nbsp;place
</p>
<ul>
    <li data-mce-style="-webkit-margin-before: 0px; -webkit-margin-after: 0px; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 14px; background-color: #f7f7f7;">with forests,</li>
    <li data-mce-style="-webkit-margin-before: 0px; -webkit-margin-after: 0px; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 14px; background-color: #f7f7f7;">curses and faries,</li>
</ul>
<p style="text-align: justify;" data-mce-style="text-align: justify;">
    with a romantic and lovely 
    <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);" data-mce-style="color: #0000ff;">song</span>
    . A fantastic
    <sup>show</sup>.
</p>
```

A mobile front-end application (developed in Flash by another person) needs to display the text with all styling intact. However, sometimes the application doesn't show anything, and the developer says that this is because Flash doesn't like HTML tags/styles.

I was thinking that we could use a parser of some kind to convert the HTML code into something more suitable for Flash, but I couldn't find anything. I came across these two links, but I don't know anything about ActionScript, so they don't help me much:

- [AS3 TextField and StyleSheet](http://snipplr.com/view/39474/)
- [StyleSheet AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html)

Is there any simple way to convert HTML into ActionScript?

Comment: You can't convert HTML into ActionScript. HTML is a *markup* language used to describe the structure of web pages, and ActionScript is a *programming* language similar to Javascript. It seems to me that you are actually trying to do something else, but it's not clear what - please [re-phrase your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29101203/edit) so that we can understand your situation better.

Comment: @GoBusto I don't know how my colleague presents in Flash the object I sent to him from database but I think he set something with the html code string. But he says 'Flash don't like html styles' or 'Flash don't like tag' because sometimes flash application don't presents anything, neither text

Comment: Flash text fields do support *some* HTML tags. According to the [SWF spec](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf), *"...Dynamic text also has many formatting capabilities that static text does not have. __These rich formatting capabilities are expressed as a subset of HTML text markup tags.__"* See pages 173-174 of that document for a list of HTML tags supported by Flash.

Comment: That help me better than the [StyleSheet AS3] link I posted above. But so @GoBusto you recommend parse html code in the flash side instead backoffice server side?

Comment: If I'm understanding your situation correctly, the text stored in the database contains HTML tags (example: `<p>Hello, <b>World!</b></p>`) and this is passed through to the Flash front-end program. Since Flash text fields **with HTML support enabled** are able to handle common tags such as `<b>` or `<i>`, I'm not sure why there would be any problems. I'd suggest that you talk to the person who handles the Flash program about the **supported** tags mentioned in [the document I linked to before](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf).

Comment: @GoBusto yes. Right now I'm replacing in <strong> tags with <b> tags, and <em> with <i> tags. But and the other html code?! The data attributes `data-mce-style` that can't exist?! The css `text-decoration` which must be `textDecoration`?! And the RGB colors that must be hex colores?! Replacing all that one by one is not the better way and I need a better solution...

Comment: `data-mce-style` is not an HTML attribute, its a custom attribute used by MCE in some way. Basically the code you've stored in the database is very specific to MCE so you are going to have to do some custom conversion. And as you've already discovered the supported subset of HTML/CSS in an TextField is very limited. If your client is using AIR, you could use `HTMLLoader` or `StageWebView` to get a full HTML renderer.

Comment: @Ninita You might be able to do it via `StageWebView`/`HTMLLoader` if you are using AIR, but you lose most control and it is very difficult to integrate. Otherwise, there is no better option. Flash is **not** an HTML renderer and is really poor at it. Even the things it does support are extremely slow. Your options are really limited if you insist on using Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "simple way" unfortunately.

As you've already discovered, the `TextField` class does support basic HTML and CSS rendering via `htmlText` and `styleSheet` properties, but the [supported tags](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) and [styles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html) are very limited. In some cases you can convert tags (using `RegExp` or simple string searching) to get close to the original styles.

Additionally, things like `data-mce-style` is specific to MCE, so you'll have to convert it to something meaningful in HTML.

If you are using **AIR** you can use `HTMLLoader` or `StageWebView`. Both of these classes use a full HTML rendering engine (WebKit or the native web renderer).

Finally, and this may be your best option, in a web browser you can overlay a `<div>` over the SWF (with `wmode=opaque` or `transparent`) and display the HTML in the browser.

Comment: A quick note on `StageWebView`, which I alluded to in my comment: if you are planning to integrate this text into your interface in any way at all, this is not a viable solution since `StageWebView` overlays your app and is completely opaque. Unless you add the interface into the HTML itself, it will just be a solid color with text on it, in the middle of your app. Regardless, this is a good answer.